# Estoy creando una WebAPI y no logro hacer que mi conexión a base de datos sqlserver funcione

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

Quizá esta pregunta ya se ha realizado pero no encuentro solución a mi problema en particular. Estoy intentado hacer una api en c#, estoy usando visual studio y sql server manangement.
Pero no he podido avanzar debido a este error, originalmente estoy siguiendo un tutorial en youtube pero a la persona no le pasa esto, no le sale este error. He buscado distintas soluciones pero llego siempre al mismo error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No hay ningún proceso en el otro extremo de la canalización.)'

Excepción interna
Win32Exception: No hay ningún proceso en el otro extremo de la canalización.
```

Ya he intentado validar las credenciales del usuario, crear otro login, he cerrado y abierto los programas. He habilitado los servicios SQL Server y SQL Server Agent, al igual que los protocoles Shared Memory, Named Pipes y TCP/IP. Incluso re instale el SMSS siguiendo un tutorial para asegurarme de instalar todas las dependencias necesarias aún así sigo varado. Quisiera saber si hay algo que pueda hacer

En mi archivo appsettings.json tengo esto

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
"CadenaSQL": "Data Source=(local);InitialCatalog=ApiCrudDB;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
  } UserID=apiAdmin; Password=1234,
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el json que pusiste es tal cual como lo tienes en tu app, ese es el problema. Está mal formateado, esto es lo correcto con los datos que tienes:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "CadenaSQL": "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=ApiCrudDB;TrustServerCertificate=True;UserID=apiAdmin;Password=1234"
}
```